# How do I manage the existing repositories that show up when I use Subversive?

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, subversive

When I create a new project from SVN the wizard pops up and instructs me to either "Create a new repository location" or "Use existing repository location". I want to remove most of the existing repositories or at least modify them but I don't see any options in Eclipse to edit or delete them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can switch to SVN Repository Exploring and then change the properties of the repositories or discard them